# Firebase/JWT encryption with public Key

Tags: php, encryption, jwt, encryption-asymmetric

Hi i'm developing an architecture with an application authorization server(AS) and some client applications(CA) in PHP.
Users that are signing in a CA will login by SSO on AS and on success will be redirect to CA with  some parameters stored in a JWT token.
I generate a pair of keys to implement asymmetric encryption, where private is secret and stored on the AS and public is shared around CAs.

I'm using Firebase/JWT library for PHP and i'm able to encode token generated by AS using `JWT::encode($this->token, $privateKey, 'RS256')` with AS private key.
At the same way the CA receives the token and decode it using
`JWT::decode($jwt_token, $key, array('RS256'))`
and all works fine...

But i want to introduce another secure step at the beginning.
I want generate a token in the CA(with the same library), containing referral CA infos (like app code, and other CA parameters to send to AS)   before this were redirect to AS for login and i want to encrypt this token with public shared key of AS so that only AS can decrypt the token with its own private key.
In simple words Bob(CA) encrypt a message with Alice's(AS) public key so that only Alice can decrypt it with her own private key.

I'm trying to do that with same method
`JWT::encode($this->token, $_ALICES_PUBLIC_KEY, 'RS256')`

but it seems that the `JWT::encode` method only accept PRIVATE type keys and i'm getting the following error
**PHP Warning:  openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key**

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: in `JWT::encode` the key is only used for the signature (i.e. encrypt a hash of header+payload and add it as a signature to the token). `JWT::encode` does NOT encrypt the payload/data which you're sending. And signing with a public key usually doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @jps thanks for answer. Signing with public key guarantees that only AS can read the hash of header+payload that is what i'm looking for. Can you help for this? or have you better solution?

Comment: A signature is a cryptographic hash that provides message verification and non-repudiation, _not_ encryption. You cannot simply put a different key type into the signature function and turn it into encryption. You can apply JWE to encrypt the _body_ of the JWT, but you cannot encrypt the header. If you want to encrypt the whole thing, then what you actually want is to protect the entire session with TLS.

Comment: I meant 'Encrypting' not 'signing' with public key in the past comment. However, i just want to encrypt the payload  data sent, with public key. what Firebase/Jwt function should i use? Is it possible?

Comment: if you want to send some information encrypted (on top of TLS) from A to B, you might consider JWE instead of JWT. JWT really doesn't help in that case, because the payload is just base64 encoded and can be read by everyone. But I think now it's time for some research and consideration on your side. The original question can be closed/deleted now, because what you asked (JWT with public key) is not possible and doesn't make any sense.